# Calling of a python script from a browser add-on written in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, browser-addons, kango-framework

I am using the KangoExtension framework for developing an add-on. The add-on is written in JavaScript. How can I call a python-script which is a local file?

Comment: The answer is that you almost certainly can't, I believe - although I'm much more experienced with Python than Javascript. Allowing an add-on to run abitrary code would be a security nightmare. One solution would be to set up a webserver that would launch Python code upon receiving a request though, if that fits your needs.

Comment: But in Firefox I can start processes with the nsIProcess interface. I have an executable file that I can run from the add-on, which is installed in Firefox. The python script should be called direct from the add-on, without a webserver. @James